# n-dimensional plot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot 6-dimensional data using parallel axes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates). The list looks like this:

```
    {{a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f[a1,b1,c1,d1,e1]},{a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f[a2,b2,c2,d2,e2]},{},...}
```

I need to draw six vertical axes with scales on them, connect the dots with lines, and color these lines according to the value of `f[ai,bi,ci,di,ei]`, or the last coordinate.

A three dimensional example with two data would help me start, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
parallelPlot[dat_] := 
 ListPlot[dat, 
  Prolog -> 
   Table[Line[{{i, Min[dat]}, {i, Max[dat]}}], {i, 
     Length[dat[[1]]]}],
  PlotStyle -> 
   Table[Blend[{Red, Blue}, 
     Rescale[dat[[i, -1]], {Min[dat[[All, -1]]], Max[dat[[All, -1]]]}
      ]], {i, Length[dat]}],
  Joined -> True,
  Axes -> False
  ]
```

Test:

```
parallelPlot[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10, 6}]]
```

[image]

Things that one can easily add but I don't have time now:

1. Rescale each coordinate separately.
2. Ticks, labels, etc.
3. Colorbar

**======= Better function, that also rescales ========**

The [`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html) function is what you should use for rescaling. Let's keep the minimum and maximum of each dimensions in the variables `mins` and `maxs`, and thus

```
{mins, maxs} = Transpose[{Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Transpose[data]];
rescaledData = 
  Transpose@
   Table[Rescale[data[[All, i]], {mins[[i]], maxs[[i]]}], {i, Length@data[[1]]}];
```

We can then use `mins` and `maxs` to create tick labels at the bottom and top of each dimension. Here's the integrated code (I also added a [`Floor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor.html) and [`Ceiling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ceiling.html) functions in the calculation of `mins` and `maxs` to make the bounds nicer):

```
parallelPlot[data_] := Block[{mins, maxs, rescaledData, n, ndim},
   n = Length[data];
   ndim = Length[data // First];
   {mins, maxs} = Transpose[{Floor@Min[#], Ceiling@Max[#]} & /@ Transpose[data]];
   rescaledData = 
    Transpose@
     Table[Rescale[data[[All, i]], {mins[[i]], maxs[[i]]}], {i, ndim}];
   ListPlot[rescaledData,
    Prolog -> Table[Line[{{i, 0}, {i, 1}}], {i, ndim}],
    PlotStyle -> Table[Blend[{Red, Blue}, rescaledData[[i, -1]]], {i, n}],
    Epilog -> {
     Table[Text[mins[[i]] // ToString, {i, 0}, {-1, 0}], {i, ndim}], 
     Table[Text[maxs[[i]] // ToString, {i, 1}, {-1, 0}], {i,ndim}]
    },
    Joined -> True, 
    Axes -> False];
```

To test, we generate 6-dimensional random data (here its 15 points), where each coordinate is randomly distributed between two random bounds.

```
d = Transpose@Table[
        RandomReal[{Min@#, Max@#} &@RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 2], 15],
    {6}]
parallelPlot@d
```

[image]

Comment: Like your avatar :)

Comment: nice http://i.imgur.com/BFgoNIO.jpg

Comment: @Silvia thx. Yours ain't bad neither :)

Comment: It was a rose in my garden :)

Comment: @yohbs  When you have time can you explain how I can do the rescaling?

Comment: Now that you've accepted my answer, I don't have any incentive to do so...  Just kidding, I will add it later, maybe tonight.

Comment: @user27670 I added the rescaling code.

Comment: I've just seen the update. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I took another stab at the problem to produce a self-contained function that generates axes as well as rescales the data. The function `nplot` is defined below. It takes a list of data as input

```
Clear[nplot]

nplot[data_?(ArrayQ[#, 2, NumericQ] &), ImageSize -> size_] := Module[
  {rescaled, plot, axes},
  rescaled = Transpose@(Rescale /@ Transpose@data);
  plot =
   ListLinePlot[
    rescaled, PlotRange -> {{1, Last@Dimensions@data}, Automatic},
    ImageSize -> size, PlotRangePadding -> None, Axes -> None
   ];
  axes =
   Map[
    ListPlot[
      data[[All, #]], PlotStyle -> None, 
      PlotRange -> {{1, Last@Dimensions@data}, Automatic},
      Axes -> {False, True}, PlotRangePadding -> None,
      ImageSize -> size, Background -> None, 
      AxesOrigin -> {#, Automatic}] &,
    Range[Last@Dimensions@data]
   ];
  Overlay[Flatten@{plot, axes}]
]

nplot[data_] := nplot[data, ImageSize -> Automatic]
```

Within `nplot` I generate a column-wise rescaled version of the data that is plotted using `ListLinePlot`; the axes of this plot are suppressed, because they will be replaced by more appropriate ones reflecting the non-rescaled value of the variables. I then use the existing `ListPlot` machinery to generate appropriately scaled and placed axes for the non-rescaled data, which are stored in `axes` within `nplot`.
Finally, the rescaled plot and non-rescaled axes are overlaid and returned.

The function checks the nature of the input data (it must be at least a 2-dimensional array: a vector would result in a straight line across the plot and would be very uninteresting) and passes through values of the *ImageSize* option, if set by the user (otherwise a value of `Automatic` is used).

---

Here is what the function produces with some random input:

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {15, 6}];
nplot[pts, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: n-dimensional plot output]

Comment: Nice. I thought about using `Overlay`, but the problem is that this produces an object which is not a `Graphics`, and thus is not amenable to further manipulations. But if this is not an issue then that's probably a simpler approach.

Comment: @yohbs That's very true. I have been trying to get around that limitation, but for now I'm still stuck with `Overlay` in order to harness a plotting function to auto-generate the axes. I have been looking around for pre-made functions that generate axes, or for access to the built-in ones, but no joy so far.

Comment: I opened a thread to see if someone solved it. You're [welcome to join](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94726/plotting-an-axis-with-ticks).